# A way to incorporate image responsive class in sphinx RST?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, python-sphinx

So in using the `rst` format for `sphinx`, image can be included into the webpage using:

```
.. image:: images/pic.png
    :align: center
```

But this won't work with the responsive bootstrap where the class `img-responsive` is required instead. Is there a way to work around this? At the moment my solution is writing html raw code:

```
.. raw:: html

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <img src="images/pic.png" class="img-responsive"> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

But this is rather clumsy. Is there a neater way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking for the same thing and found your question sadly with no answers. After more searching, I did come across this Sphinx extension:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinxcontrib-css3image

Basically it lets you specify additional settings in a new directive (based on image) which you use like this:

```
.. css3image:: /_images/foo.png
  :margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px
  :margin-left: 10px
  :margin-right: 10px
  :margin-top: 10px
  :border-radius: 10px
  :transform-origin: 10px 10px
  :translate: 10px 10px
  :translateY: 10px
  :translateX: 10px
  :scaleX: 2.0
  :scaleY: 2.0
  :rotate: -10deg
```

I also noticed in the source code that it looks like you can specify the class:

https://github.com/FabriceSalvaire/sphinx-css3image/blob/master/sphinxcontrib/css3image.py#L123-L148

I just installed it and played around with it a bit. Seems like it's doing at least part of what you want?

Comment: Ah the brave scavenger! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but better late than never.

There is now a Sphinx extension that creates responsive images. Take a look at https://github.com/sphinxext-photofinish

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).